# Заменить список списком

Tags: python

Хотелось бы узнать: есть ли стандартная функция или библиотеки, способная в двухмерном списке list1(переменная длина) заменить элементы начиная с позиции 0 до конца элементами из тоже двухмерного списка list2(переменная длина)?

Например, изначальные списки выглядят так:

```
list1 = [[1,1,1,1,1],[4,4,4,4,4]] 
list2 = [[2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

А после работы функции/библиотеки мы получаем следующее:

```
result = [
        [[2,2,1,1,1],
         [1,2,2,1,1],
         [1,1,2,2,1],
         [1,1,1,2,2]],
        [[2,2,4,4,4],
         [4,2,2,4,4], итд],
         [3,3,3,1,1],
         [1,3,3,3,1], итд]
        ]
```

и тому подобное, буду крайне признателен. Спасибо!

Comment: Просто интересно, зачем это вообще может быть нужно?

Comment: @whizz169 такая форма данных необходима для входых значений в нейронную сеть.

Comment: элементы list2 гарантированно короче элементов list1?